# Kubeconform helm pre-commit plugin is skipping files

Tags: git, kubernetes-helm, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have a helms folder structure and am trying to run the kubeconform pre-commit hook to test my yaml files. However, I everytime I run it, the files just get skipped.

```
Project
├── Makefile
├── helms
│   └── test-files
│       ├── Chart.yaml
│       ├── templates
│       │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│       │   ├── test-configmap.yaml
│       │   ├── test-deployment.yaml
│       │   ├── test-service.yaml
│       └── values.yaml
├──.pre-commit-config.yaml
```

These are the contents of `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```
    repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/jtyr/kubeconform-helm
    rev: v0.1.16
    hooks:
      - id: kubeconform-helm
        args:
          - --verbose
          - --summary
```

This is what I am running in my terminal:

```
pre-commit run --all-files
```

This is the output:

```
Kubeconform Helm.....................................(no files to check)Skipped
```

Answer (score 1):

by default this repo uses [this file filter list](https://github.com/jtyr/kubeconform-helm/blob/aeaabe4884eb0caa2570f767dc07131ecb46e579/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml#L5C31-L6C104):

```
  files: ^(helper-|)charts/[^/]+/(\.kubeconform|\.helmignore|templates/NOTES.txt|.*\.(ya?ml|json|tpl))$
```

if your charts do not match that you will need to override `files` with a more appropriate pattern

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit